# Why does apt-get marks packages I dont want directly?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, administration

If I try to install metapackage `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and then see the output of `apt-mark showmanual | grep lubuntu` I see much more than just `lubuntu-desktop`:

```
lubuntu-artwork
lubuntu-core
lubuntu-deskto
```

So, `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` marks as manually installed not just the package `lubuntu-desktop` but also it's dependencies or something. But I don't need those packages directly and this behaviour is weird and unexpected.

Is there any way to configure `apt` to mark as manually installed just those packages I install by hands, not with their dependencies or something like that?

Comment: So... You know lubuntu-desktop is not a single package, but a group of packages, right?

Comment: @EduardoCola no, I did not. Where can I read about groups of packages and how do they differ from just empty packages with dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick search through apt sources gave me (1). As far as I understand, packages which are in section listed in `APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections`, when installed mark their *immediate* dependencies as manual. So that installing a metapackage which required, for example, browser, then removing the metapackage leaves the browser installed. This seems to be intended behavior. Should be possible to change by clearing the default `APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections` value.

(1) http://sources.debian.net/src/apt/1.1.9/apt-pkg/depcache.cc/?hl=849#L843

Comment: rather https://sources.debian.org/src/apt/1.6~alpha5/apt-pkg/depcache.cc/#L856

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware):

**Package Dependencies**

> Programs often use some of the same files as each other. Rather than
> putting these files into each package, a separate package can be
> installed to provide them for all of the programs that need them. So,
> to install a program which needs one of these files, the package
> containing those files must also be installed. When a package depends
> on another in this way, it is known as a package dependency. By
> specifying dependencies, packages can be made smaller and simpler, and
> duplicates of files and programs are mostly removed.
>
> When you install a program, its dependencies must be installed at the
> same time. Usually, most of the required dependencies will already be
> installed, but a few extras may be needed, too. So, when you install a
> package, don't be surprised if several other packages are installed
> too - these are just dependencies which are needed for your chosen
> package to function properly.

As per your question,

`lubuntu-desktop` depends on the following:

```
lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-core lubuntu-desktop ...
```

Thus, the command `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` installs them as well. It's inevitable.

**EDIT**: From [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/apt-mark.8.html):

> apt-mark
>
> ```
>        apt-mark will change whether a package has been marked as being
>        automatically installed.
>        When you request that a package is installed, and as a result other
>        packages are installed to satisfy its dependencies, the dependencies
>        are marked as being automatically installed. Once these automatically
>        installed packages are no longer depended on by any manually installed
>        packages, they will be removed by e.g.  apt-get or aptitude.
> ```
>
> showauto
>
> ```
>        showauto is used to print a list of automatically installed
>        packages with each package on a new line. All automatically
>        installed packages will be listed if no package is given. If
>        packages are given only those which are automatically installed will be shown.
> ```
>
> showmanual
>
> ```
>        showmanual can be used in the same way as showauto except that it
>        will print a list of manually installed packages instead.
> ```

It already says in the manpages, that it will also include its dependencies.

Comment: I am talking about marking packages as manually installed (see `man apt-mark`), not about installing dependencies. From man: `manual is used to mark a package as being manually installed, which will prevent the package from being automatically removed if no other packages depend on it.`. So when I install `lubuntu-desktop` other packages are also marked as installed manual, which is unexpected as I said. Your answer is not related to question.

Comment: @s9gf4ult - Edited

Comment: `It already says in the manual, that it will also include its dependencies.`

Documentation says, that 

`the dependencies are marked as being automatically installed`

But in my case dependencies are marked as installed manually, not automatically. This is the pint.

Comment: @s9gf4ult - Automatically for `showauto` and manual for `showmanual`

Comment: @s9gf4ult - you did install lubuntu manually by typing `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` right?

Comment: yes, `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @s9gf4ult - So you installed it manually

Comment: @Rahpael yes, but `apt-mark showmanual` shows not just `lubuntu-desktop` (which I actually installed manually) but also some of its dependencies, like `lubuntu-desktop-artwork` and so on. And this is unexpected behaviour.